# Is the memory stacking order different on rPi B vs rpi 2?

Tags: hardware

This [question about Package-on-Package RAM/CPU](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31325/where-is-rpi-512mb-memory-located-in-the-board) got me curious: My rPi B has the Samsung RAM packaged on top of the Broadcom (as I can read the Samsung product details off of the package). My rPi 2 B has the Broadcom on top of the RAM (as I can read the Broadcom product details off of the package). Is there a reason why the stacking order is different between versions, or is it different from batch-to-batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RAM on the Raspberry Pi 2 is not underneath the Broadcom chip, it's on the underside of the Pi.

Comment: So they stopped doing PoP, do you know why?

Comment: I think it was a matter of cost. PoP is quite expensive.

Comment: PoP limited the memory to 500M because this was the largest package available.

Comment: AIUI the reason for moving the memory to the bottom of the board is that the processor die was too big to fit in the PoP package.